# Why is my function call not working when returning a boolean?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Why is my function call not evaluating to boolean in the if condition below?

Do you have to use numerics for boolean when returning from function call?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script to wait for log file to start and open it using less
function is_log_started()
{
        if test -f "log/server.log"; then
                return true
        fi
        return false
}

if [ is_log_started = true ]; then
        echo "log started"
fi
```

Comment: FYI, `true` and `false` are actually valid bash commands which return 0 and 1, respectively. (Quite unexpected if you only used java-like languages before).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only return an integer between 0 and 255 from a shell function. That's the same restriction that applies to an executable. Different shells react differently if you pass a non-numeric argument; bash does print out an error message.

```
$ bash -c 'f () { return true; }; f; echo $?'                    
bash: line 0: return: true: numeric argument required
2
```

Pass 0 for true and any value from 1 to 125 for false, same as when exiting from a program. Values from 126 to 255 are also false, but they have a conventional meaning (unable to start a program, or program killed by a signal).

```
function is_log_started()
{
        if test -f "log/server.log"; then
                return 0
        fi
        return 1
}
```

But this is a complex way of writing

```
function is_log_started
{
        test -f "log/server.log"
}
```

The return status from a shell function is the return status of the last statement that is executed.

Your test is also wrong. `[ is_log_started = true ]` tests whether `is_log_started` and `true` are the same string. To test if the return status of a function call is true, you just call the function. Every shell command is already a boolean: true if the command returns 0, false otherwise.

```
function is_log_started
{
        test -f "log/server.log"
}
if is_log_started; then
    echo "log started"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Coming from a world of Java programming, I tend to like descriptive code.

Answer (score 3):

You may know this already, but you could take out the function entirely and just use:

```
if [ -f "log/server.log" ] ; then echo "log started" ; fi
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is written you are comparing the strings "is_log_started" and "true" which is always false.

Your test should be:

```
if is_log_started; then
```

and your function should really return true (0) or false (e.g. 1) for the test to complete.