# bash function call in while loop

Tags: linux, bash

I receive an error: "/bin/ums: 19: [: is_duplicate: unexpected operator" when running the following script:

```
#! /bin/sh                                                                      
                                                                                
group=""                                                                        
                                                                                
#utility functions                                                              
                                                                                
is_duplicate () {                                                               
                                                                                
  return grep $1 /etc/passwd /etc/group                                         
                                                                                
}                                                                               
                                                                                
#script                                                                         
                                                                                
echo "Welcome to the user management system."                                   
echo "Please enter the name of the group you wish to create:"                   
read group                                                                      
                                                                                
while [ is_duplicate "$group" -eq 0 ]                                           
do                                                                              
  echo "That group name already exists."                                        
  echo "Please enter a new name:"                                               
  read group                                                                    
done
```

Why?

Note: The script is a work in progress. In this segment I am trying to grep for the name of a group being input in the console. If the group exists in the group file (i.e. grep returns exit code 0) then continue asking for a name.

Comment: run your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/, and have a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232421/170373

Answer (score 0):

To test the success as indicated by the zero exit code no parentheses are needed.

```
while is_duplicate "$group" ; do
...
done
```

Similarly, `return` expects a number, not the string `grep`. You can call `grep` without `return` as the last thing in the function, its exit code will be returned.

But you should be more specific in what you're grepping from the files.

```
grep $1 /etc/passwd /etc/group
```

will return true even for user names or shell paths.

At least, quote the `$1` (and maybe validate it a bit, you can try what e.g. `-v :` does).

Comment: `grep -wF "$1"` would be a better match. Or even `awk -v ug="$1" '$1==ug {exit 0} END {exit 1}'`

Comment: Thanks for the insight - removing parenthesis seems to have worked. Why does including them cause the error?

Comment: The syntax of `[` is explained in `man bash`. It should start with `-z` or similar, or with any word followed by `-eq` and similar. It can't start with two unknown words `is_duplicate` and the group name (unless the group name is `-eq` etc., but then only one value is expected, not two, `-eq 0`.)